# Oracle | Select * besides <column_name>

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select all columns from the table besides two or three?
I work with a lot of tables with more than 50 columns, so I can not list of column name...

I hope that it works, but it doesn't

```
SELECT(
SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = <table_name>
AND column_name NOT IT (<columns_name>)
)
from <table_name>;
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you saying that suppose a table has `col1,col2....col50`. Then you want to select all columns except say `col2,col4,col6 etc`. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean you can't list the column names? What prevents you?

Comment: Utsav, you are right. that case.

Comment: Not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+select+*+except+one

Comment: ok. thank you! 
I could not find the search, do not know the query

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the query dynamically through a pl/sql procedure and then run it using "execute immediate"

Comment: yeah, PL - yes, but I found way to solve this task by SQL... as it turned out - it is immposible(

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround (because PL/SQL to hard for simple select):

```
CREAT TABLE <tmp> AS SELECT * FROM <table_name>;
ALTER TALBE <tmp> DROP COLUMN <column_name>;
SELECT * FROM <tmp>;
DROP TALBE <tmp>;
```

It will be useful to simple query...
But for development PL/SQL will be more useful (universally, optimized for server, etc).

Comment: Let me get that straight - you say PL/SQL is too hard and *duplicate your table instead* ???? Why not simply create a view that contains only the columns you want?

Comment: Frank, I provided note that PL is very useful for DEV team, 
but it is not useful to executed single query manual with different lists of columns.